# Flex Colum Structure

Tags: html, css, flexbox

I am strugling with a CSS flex design which would design something like below image.

[image]

```css
.container {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  height: 400px;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
  max-width:400px;
}
.col {
  border: 1px solid #333;

}
.item-0 {
  order: 1;
}
.item-1 {
  order: 2;
}
.item-2 {
  order: 3;
}
@media only screen and (max-width: 767px) {
  .container {
    height: auto;
  }
  .col {
    border: 1px solid #333;
  }
  .item-0 {
    order: 1;
  }
  .item-1 {
    order: 3;
  }
  .item-2 {
    order: 2;
  }
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="item-0 col">1<br/>
  Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text ever since the 1500s, when an unknown printer took a galley of type and scrambled it to make a type specimen book. It has survived not only five centuries, but also the leap into electronic typesetting, remaining essentially unchanged. It was popularised in the 1960s with the release of Letraset sheets containing Lorem Ipsum passages, and more recently with desktop publishing software like Aldus PageMaker including versions of Lorem Ipsum.</div>
  <div class="item-1 col">2<br/>
    Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text ever since the 1500s, when an unknown printer took a galley of type and scrambled it to make a type specimen book. It has survived not only five centuries, but also the leap into electronic typesetting, remaining essentially unchanged. It was popularised in the 1960s with the release of Letraset sheets containing Lorem Ipsum passages, and more recently with desktop publishing software like Aldus PageMaker including versions of Lorem Ipsum.
  </div>
  <div class="item-2 col">3<br/>
  Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text ever since the 1500s, when an unknown printer took a galley of type and scrambled it to make a type specimen book. It has survived not only five centuries, but also the leap into electronic typesetting, remaining essentially unchanged. It was popularised in the 1960s with the release of Letraset sheets containing Lorem Ipsum passages, and more recently with desktop publishing software like Aldus PageMaker including versions of Lorem Ipsum.
  Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text ever since the 1500s, when an unknown printer took a galley of type and scrambled it to make a type specimen book. It has survived not only five centuries, but also the leap into electronic typesetting, remaining essentially unchanged. It was popularised in the 1960s with the release of Letraset sheets containing Lorem Ipsum passages, and more recently with desktop publishing software like Aldus PageMaker including versions of Lorem Ipsum.
  Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text ever since the 1500s, when an unknown printer took a galley of type and scrambled it to make a type specimen book. It has survived not only five centuries, but also the leap into electronic typesetting, remaining essentially unchanged. It was popularised in the 1960s with the release of Letraset sheets containing Lorem Ipsum passages, and more recently with desktop publishing software like Aldus PageMaker including versions of Lorem Ipsum.</div>
</div>
```

Now, Its working fine on codepen but when i am trying to integrate it on my application it breaking.
Items are aligned on code pen but its not working on a desktop viewport with max-width:1200px.

https://codepen.io/ritesh14887/pen/OJbJrLw

TIA..

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/0typmx6d/

Comment: @ritesh-kashyap - found any solution to achieve this layout?